# Iterate over object and build constructor

Tags: javascript

So I'm reading values from an Excel workbook and am trying to figure out how to create a constructor function from said values. I iterate over the worksheet object which contains the values and compare it to my map object to grab the relevant values

```
const map = {
  E: 'E',
  F: 'F',
  G: 'G',
  H: 'H',
  I: 'I',
  J: 'J',
  K: 'K',
  L: 'L',
  M: 'M',
  N: 'N',
  O: 'O',
  P: 'P',
  Q: 'Q',
  R: 'R',
  S: 'S',
  T: 'T',
  U: 'U'
};
for (var z in worksheet) {
  if ( map[z[0]] && z[1] === '4' && z.length === 2 ) {
    values[z] = worksheet[z]
  }
}
```

Currently I'm putting the values in the values object, but I realized I need to put them into a constructor like:

```
function Row(fieldCode, operatorCode, reportMonth, luwCode, facilityCode, numOfWells, parishCode, openingStock, condensationProduction, transporterCode,
dispositionType, dispositionAmount, closingStock, gasProduction, luwName, orig) {
  this.fieldCode = fieldCode;
  this.reportMonth = reportMonth;
  this.luwCode = luwCode;
  this.facilityCode = facilityCode;
  this.numOfWells = numOfWells;
  this.parishCode = parishCode;
  this.openingStock = openingStock;
  this.condensationProduction = condensationProduction;
  this.transporterCode = transporterCode;
  this.dispositionType = dispositionType;
  this.dispositionAmount = dispositionAmount;
  this.closingStock = closingStock;
  this.gasProduction = gasProduction;
  this.luwName = luwName;
  this.orig = orig;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can pass the values from the values object into the constructor?

EDIT
I'm trying get the key/value like so

```
const values = {
  fieldCode: '4451',
  operatorCode: '6548',
  reportMonth: '11'
  ...
}
```

Comment: May not be pertinent to question, but your map is invalid. You have the key 'Q' repeated twice.

Comment: @rasmeister good alphabetic notice!

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do... you're reading from a spreadsheet by row, and mapping the column values to an object? Why do you want to use a constructor? Are you going to have other methods that need to be attached to the object along with the values?

Comment: Woops, fixed the issue with repeating Q.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it properly. I want to use a constructor because I need to transform the values in order ot submit them somewhere else. I'm essentially just trying to attach the values to their corresponding column name. I'm editing the initial question to reflect this

Comment: Probably going to be a lot easier just to pass all of your arguments in one object and assign those to `this`: `function Row(properties) {
   Object.assign(this, properties);
}`